# how to change header info in mp3 file?

Tags: java, android

Below are my queries.

1.What information is there in header field of mp3 file?

2.If i need to change like bitrate,length,is it possible to change programatically.

3.Is it necessary that all mp3 contains id3 tag?

4.is there anyway that if i change some info in mp3 file it cant be played and if i redo it can be played?

regards,
hitendrasinh gohil

Answer (score 4):

1. See [ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) or [MP3 file structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure) if that's missing from the file.
2. You can't change something like the bitrate without re-encoding the audio stream. You can change information in the ID3 like song title and artist.
3. No, however you'll unlikely find many without one these days.
4. Depends on what you do to the file. If you just change information in the ID3 I'm not sure that you can actually make it unplayable (though likely if you corrupt it such that it's not a recognized ID3 header it won't play).

You'll probably want to take a look at the [Java ID3 Tag Library](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/).

**Update:** In your comment you said you just want to be able to make it so an mp3 can't be played and then have the ability to reverse it. In that case you could just XOR some bytes in the file with some value to make it unplayable. Then repeat the process with the same value for the same bytes and it'd be returned back to normal. Here's an example of XOR'ing the first 65536 bytes with 34:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("my.mp3", "rw");
byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
int len = raf.read(buf);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    buf[i] ^= 34;
}
raf.seek(0);
raf.write(buf);
raf.close();
```

This makes the mp3 unplayable for me. Repeating it makes it playable again.

Comment: hi,i just want to change the mp3 file info so that it cant be played but when i want to play it just replace the original content so that it can be played.

Comment: i have tried your code but it plays mp3 file.so what can i append with buffer that mp3 cant be played.