# how to remove header information from mp3 file?

Tags: java, android

is there anyway to remove header information from mp3 file such that mp3 file can't be played?

regards,
hitendrasinh gohil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do more than remove the header to make an mp3 unplayable. If you take my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802858/how-to-change-header-info-in-mp3-file/5803026#5803026) to your question and apply it to the *whole* file there should be no way it can be played:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("input.mp3", "rw");
byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
long pos = 0;
int len;
Random random = new Random(34);
while ((len = raf.read(buf)) != -1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        buf[i] ^= random.nextInt();
    }
    raf.seek(pos);
    raf.write(buf);
    pos = raf.getFilePointer();
}
raf.close();
```

This will XOR every byte in the file. The only reason I suggested in the other answer to only do the first 64k was for performance since you're on an Android device. For me that made it unplayable on my desktop. If doing the whole file doesn't work for you then I suspect you're doing something else wrong. There no way it'll play the original music if every byte is changed like this. You can run this again to undo it and make the mp3 playable again.

Comment: hi thankx everyone for replying.if i have did xor for first 64kb then it works fine for desktop but in android the song plays with noise.

Comment: the above answer is helpful for desktop.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. The Android device must still try to play it even though it's scrambled. I updated the answer to randomize (with a seed so it's reversible) the output better, which might help make it unplayable. What are you trying to accomplish by making it unplayable?

Answer (score 0):

MP3s are organized in frames so you can often still play them even you only have a part of them.